# MySQL Foreign key to existing table, delete child violations

Tags: mysql

I would like to add a FK on an existing table already populated with data with cascade on delete.  Does anyone know if it's possible to automatically delete all of the data that's in violation of the constraint so the FK can be added without needing to manually cleanup the database.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what we call "automatically".
If we are talking about the execution of SQL-query, it is not difficult to implement.
All we need to do is select the "wrong" rows and delete them.
How to do this, it is best to show on example.

Suppose we have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `products` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `name` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
 `type` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `types` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `type` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

We want to add foreign key to `products` table:

```
ALTER TABLE `products` 
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_some_key` FOREIGN KEY (`type`) REFERENCES `types` (`id`) 
    ON DELETE Cascade ON UPDATE Cascade
```

We need to remove all rows from `products` table where field `type` do not match the `types`.`id`

First, we'll make a **SELECT** query to make sure we've selected the right rows:

```
SELECT `products`.*
FROM `products` LEFT JOIN `types`
ON `products`.`type` = `types`.`id`
WHERE `types`.`id` IS NULL
```

If selection looks OK, change **SELECT** to **DELETE**:

```
DELETE `products`.*
FROM `products` LEFT JOIN `types`
ON `products`.`type` = `types`.`id`
WHERE `types`.`id` IS NULL
```

Now we have a table that is ready to add a foreign key.

Comment: That will work, thanks.  I just wasn't sure if there was anything built into mysql that would do this at the time of FK creation.

Comment: @user1279156, If you need (by any reason) to add foreign key to non-empty table, it's really important to make SELECT query before it, just to see what data will be lost (or need to be updated). And when you'll have such query, it's very easy to convert it to DELETE query. So actually you don't need any additional automatic instruments.

Comment: Great answer. This just saved me hours